# Remove all tags from unwanted Namespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxb, tags

I want to parse XML files from users. They may contain tags from a defined list of XML NS-URLs.

But some do have 'extensions' from namespaces not on our list -  so our jaxb-parser crashes.

Is there any XSL out there which removes all namespaces and their tags which are not on a whitelist?

Comment: What does remove mean exactly? If you have an element in a namespace not on your whitelist but it has children or descendants on the whitelist, do you want to remove the element completely or do you want to keep the children/descendants?

Comment: You say "tags", but you mean elements (or nodes). Also, namespaces cannot be "removed". You can remove nodes that are (or aren't) in a given namespace. Or you can move them to a different namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following example:

**XML**

```
<root xmlns="http://www.example.com/a">
    <item xmlns="http://www.example.com/b">
        <sub-item>bravo</sub-item>
    </item>
    <item xmlns="http://www.example.com/x">
        <sub-item>x-ray</sub-item>
    </item>
    <item xmlns="http://www.example.com/c">
        <sub-item>charlie</sub-item>
    </item>
</root>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/my"
exclude-result-prefixes="my">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<my:allowed-namespaces>
    <uri>http://www.example.com/a</uri>
    <uri>http://www.example.com/b</uri>
    <uri>http://www.example.com/c</uri>
</my:allowed-namespaces>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[not(namespace-uri()=document('')/xsl:stylesheet/my:allowed-namespaces/uri)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="http://www.example.com/a">
  <item xmlns="http://www.example.com/b">
    <sub-item>bravo</sub-item>
  </item>
  <item xmlns="http://www.example.com/c">
    <sub-item>charlie</sub-item>
  </item>
</root>
```